# How to break subquery into 2 simple query

Tags: database, sqlite, subquery

I am trying some way to optimize following sql statement:

```
exe_sql "DELETE FROM tblEvent_type WHERE eguid in (SELECT rowid FROM tblEvent_basic WHERE sguid=11);";
exe_sql "DELETE FROM tblEvent_group WHERE eguid in (SELECT rowid FROM tblEvent_basic WHERE sguid=11);";
```

It is said that sqlite3 did not perform well in subquery and notice that above two sql excuted "(SELECT rowid FROM tblEvent_basic WHERE sguid=11)"` twice ,so I'd like to try to split the subquery to something like below:

```
result =  exe_sql "(SELECT rowid FROM tblEvent_basic WHERE sguid=11);";
          exe_sql "DELETE FROM tblEvent_type WHERE eguid in  (result)
          exe_sql "DELETE FROM tblEvent_group WHERE eguid in (result)
```

How could achieve this? I have no idea how to get the parmater (result) binding to follwing statment in sqlite.

```
"DELETE FROM tblEvent_group WHERE eguid in (?) #how to bind result here
```

I am using sqlite3  C API directly.

Comment: from what environment are you calling this? which language and database access frameworks are you using?

Comment: I am using sqlite3 C API on embeded system. No database access framework.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You actually need Common Table Expressions (CTE), but that's not supported in SQLite.

Another option would be to store the result of the first query in a temporary table and then use that table in both delete statements:

```
CREATE TEMP TABLE items AS SELECT rowid FROM tblEvent_basic WHERE sguid=11

DELETE FROM tblEvent_type WHERE eguid in  (select rowid from items)
DELETE FROM tblEvent_group WHERE eguid in (select rowid from items)

DROP TABLE items
```

The DROP TABLE is optional, because the table only exists for the duration of the connection to the database.

Comment: Do you mean "DELETE FROM tblEvent_type WHERE eguid in (select rowid FROM items)"?  It seems following sql is not legal in sqlite3 "DELETE FROM tblEvent_group WHERE eguid in (items)"

Comment: @pier: you're right. I fixed it. Copy/paste related mistake :)

Comment: Thanks, activa. I tried your way , but there is no abviouse performance improvement. I will try some other ways..